# Set terminal title to taskbar?

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal

When I use vim to edit some file, I have the `set title` command in my `.vimrc`.
So it changes the title of the terminal.

But this changed/new title is not reflected on taskbar.

Is there any way to do that?

I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Are you using `gnome-terminal` as the tag suggests?

Answer (score 1):

When you mention 'taskbar' I assume you are running Gnome fallback or such like and you have some kind of panel with minimised application windows. I run Xfce with a traditional bottom panel. I have `set title` in my `.vimrc` and can say that the terminal title change is reflected on the 'taskbar', or rather the bottom panel, as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

The `gnome-terminal` tab is the fourth window on the panel showing `Vim` open with a script of mine called General_Backup.

It is difficult to say why the terminal's title is failing to be reflected on your 'taskbar' (panel), but I should check your `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_aliases` and see if there are any problems with your `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND` settings, and see if the prompt is being reset properly.

All I can say is that I use a special `PROMPT_COMMAND` in my `.bashrc`, which I have adapted somewhat from the commented out one in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*) PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "%b" "\033]0;${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"'
                  export PROMPT_COMMAND;;
               *) :;;
esac
```

I have found that using this `PROMPT_COMMAND` also allows you to have individual titles in your terminal tabs (denoting the current working directory), if you use, for example, `gnome-terminal`, or `guake`:

[image]

Using this `PROMPT_COMMAND` setting allows the `vim` window to revert to the present working directory when `vim` is exited; without it, `Thanks for flying Vim` remains all the time until the terminal is exited.

These tips should help you sort out the issue, but it may be a problem specific to your setup. If so, some further information might be necessary relating to the settings of your various programs.